# Static ip adress with openvpn. How to make it?

Tags: windows, openvpn, internet-connection, network-adapter

How can i do that, if i only use openvpn client? I do not have access to server config. My OS is windows 10 x64
Example: 1 client connect only 172.27.232.25 all time, no matter how many times i will restart my nic

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't.  OpenVPN is not tied to a nic or mac address, rather user credentials in the configuration.

The server does not need accept your choice of IP address, and generally shouldn't.   On the other hand, it does need to know how things are connected to it, so it is beneficial for it to set the IP address.   Using a different OpenVPN config (with different user identifiers) would let you do this, but might require a different account.

In OpenVPN, the IP address is typically set from a pool of addresses provided and allocated by the server  the "server" directive or by specifying a /30 netmask where the client and server IP are defined. (ifconfig-push statement in a "client-config-dir" file directive )

Persistence is normally kept by reference to a "ifconfig-pool-perist" command.

Comment: This is very informative answer, thank you so much.
I began to consider this option because it is a "local" adress, and thought that it can be changed from client side. But with some work, it can be done on server side right? This server is stay on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Yes, it can definitely be done on the server side.

Comment: If the VPN is in `tap` mode it is possible to change the address (to any other address from the used range) just like you change an address of any other network interface. But it is needed to be done every time you connect to server.

Comment: davidgo, what u think, it can be done by using server gui via browser on windows? ( i mean that https://12.12.12.12:943/admin)

Comment: @hashwill Sorry, other then dd-wrt  I've never seen a server GUI so I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using standart web gui. (https://yourip:943/admin) in vpn settings section.
Thanks all